# Taboem.dll error. Does anybody know what this dll file is specifically for?

Tags: windows-7, windows

**Problem**

I am currently getting an error message upon startup (Windows 7) referencing a taboem.dll file:

[image]

**Attempt**

Now I could just delete the file but of course I want to understand what it is used for.  I did try googling but got a bunch of random junk for those fake programs to supposedly fix your computer.  Does anyone know if this is used for Windows or for some other software I may have on my computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a system file.  If you are getting this error it means its corrupt.  Have you ran the SFC tool to see if the damage can be repaired?

Comment: No problems found via SFC tool.

Comment: Looks like I read the error wrong.  `wisptis.exe` isn't a system file and likely is malicious.  taboem.dll isn't corrupt its just not the version the application excepts it to be.

Comment: So I can simply remove wisptis.exe, run a virus scan to ensure nothing else is wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that taboem.dll is indeed a system file.  SFC tool resulted in everything being fine so my solution simply was to remove wisptis.exe, ran a virus check, and restarted without any more pop up messages for the error.